# Installing spotify-client on lubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, lubuntu, dependencies

I am trying to install Spotify on my Sony Vaio laptop running Lubuntu 15.10. However, whenever I run `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`, apt-get says that I
have held broken packages.
Here is the output of the install: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15172601/

Thank you!

EDIT: The laptop model is VGN-NR260E

Comment: Have you tried installing `libssl0.9.8` then running the spotify install?

Comment: I found the problem. I changed /etc/apt/sources.list from the stable repo to testing and that worked.

Comment: Cool! Post it as an answer that way if anyone else has the issue they have a resolution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently Spotify doesn't maintain their stable repository, so I changed /etc/apt/sources.list from stable to testing and everything works!